# scipy.io has no attribute 'loadmat'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to use `loadmat` from scipy.io. According to their documentation [[LINK]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html), it should be fairly easy to use `loadmat`. This is how I use it:

```
import scipy.io as sio
mat_contents = sio.loadmat('octave_a.mat')
```

I get the following error message:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'loadmat'`

I tried uninstalling and installing `numpy` and`scipy`. However, it didn't work. My `numpy` version is 1.15.1 and the `scipy` version is 1.1.0.
Here is how I install:

```
sudo -H  pip install numpy
sudo -H  pip install scipy
```

It is discouraged to install with `sudo`. Nonetheless, I cannot install with --user flag since I still get permission error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error (same versions of scipy and numpy).

Comment: @DYZ, then clearly I am making a mistake, or having incompatible stack. Can you please let me know what is the OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 18 - but it really should not matter. In fact, only the version of `scipy` matters.

Comment: What does `print(sio)` display?

Comment: @DYZ, I am using redhat. Yeah that's true. Thanks for your comments. If you can think of any solution, I would really appreciate it if you share it with me.

Comment: It displays `<module 'scipy.io' from '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/io'>`

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 I get: 

`'/home/kvnp/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/io/__init__.py'>
` and `loadmat` works for me. Can you find the loadmat code in the io path?

Comment: It should be in `pathto/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py`

Comment: try it like this..
```from scipy import io
mat_contents = io.loadmat('octave_a.mat')```
I saw it in some SO question when I was debugging for my purpose.

Comment: Last try: what is the output of `dir(sio)`?

Comment: Many scipy modules require the `from scipy import ...` syntax

Comment: Thank you guys. I realized the problem is with the permissions. I fixed it and the solution is posted below. Still I am wondering if there is clean solution for it. In addition, I wonder why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the problem is with permission. I found a way around it that can solve the problem. I fixed it by changing the permission for in `site-packages` directory as follows:

```
sudo chmod -R o+r scipy
sudo chmod -R o+r numpy
```

If there is a sophisticated solution for this problem, please feel free to post it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. However I solved it by doing the following steps

1. Dont do import scipy.io as sio ; Instead do it something like

   import scipy as sc
2. Now `mat_contents=sc.io.loadmat('octave_a.mat')`

This should resolve the problem.

Comment: You can import as sio, this is not the problem.